# Has the Spider-Man animated cartoon's (1994) intro been changed?

Tags: spider-man-the-animated-series

I recently found the old Fox Kids Spider-Man cartoon on Disney+.  Pulling up the first episode, it ran through the intro with the theme song, showing little flashes of several scenes from the first season... plus shots of Michael Morbius and The Punisher, who didn't show up until season 2!

Was the intro always like that?  If so, why did they have animation from the second season already available so early?  And if not, when did they change it?

Comment: I don't know about *Spider-Man*, but the *Gargoyles* introduction/theme song on Disney+ is not the same one that was originally aired.  It's missing the voice-over narration.  I assume, in both cases, they're just using later versions of the intros for earlier seasons.

Answer (score 1):

The first two hits on YouTube, when searching for "*Fox Kids Spider-Man*", share the same intro music, but indeed only one of them features both The Punisher and Michael Morbius, in addition to e.g. Kraven the Hunter and Venom:

| [image: shot from the video of The Punisher] | [image: shot from the video of Morbius] |
| --- | --- |

I can't tell for sure which one came first, but here is the other version, which exclusively shows Rhino (presumably as part of the Sinister Six, in season 2):

It features a lot more CGI than the first video linked, though, so I guess this could be a newer, 'hipped' version, but both videos have a mixed cast of characters from the first two seasons.